# Looking up types based on a string

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Wasn't really sure how to describe this question in the title.

Basically I'm trying to make an easy to maintain API call hook. Ideally I'd like to be able to define the different calls that are available, along with the params each one takes, and the data it returns.

If I share my failing attempt, it'll probably make more sense:

```js
interface API {
  getUser: {
    params: string,
    returnType: ApiUserResponse
  }
}

export function useApiCall(method: keyof API, params: API[method]) {

}
```

The first argument works ok, but I can't use it for subsequent arguments, or the return type. Can someone point me in the right direction here?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - this is what I settled on:

```js
interface API {
  getUser: {
    params: string
    returnType: ApiUserResponse
  }
}

export const useApiCall = async <T extends keyof API>(
  method: T,
  params: API[T]['params']
): Promise<API[T]['returnType']> => {
  const response = await axios.get<API[T]['returnType']>('some url')
  return response.data
}
```